# How can I stack editors vertically in Xcode 11?

Tags: layout, xcode11

The option to stack editors in Xcode 11 has been moved to Editor-Layout in the menu.  However the three options Automatic/Editor on Left/Editor on Top are greyed out.  How can I unlock this to arrange editors in a vertical stack?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR:** In the top bar menu under *View*, click *Change Editor Orientation*.

---

- **Option #1:** In the top bar menu under *View*, click *Change Editor Orientation*.
- **Option #2:** In the File Navigator, press `Command` + `Option` + `Control` + `T` to open the currently highlighted file in an editor below the currently active editor. This orientation switches to horizontal if the *Change Editor Orientation* option was set.
- **Option #3:** At the *Open Quickly* prompt (accessible by pressing `Command` + `Shift` + `O`), search for a file without pressing `Return` and, when a file is highlighted, press `Option` + `Shift` + `Return`. Use the arrow keys to specify where the new editor should be located.